# GitHub Action Crash on build

Tags: npm, devops, github-actions

I'm really new to the world of DevOps and want to dip my toes in the water. That's why I've been trying to set up a simple GitHub Action where my site automatically gets deployed to Firebase when I push to master but something goes wrong during the build phase:

```
Run npm run build
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/ChezMout/ChezMout/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/ChezMout/ChezMout/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-01-12T12_04_27_341Z-debug.log
##[error]Process completed with exit code 254.
```

This is my basic workflow:

```
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build 
        run: npm run build

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@v1.1.0
        with:
          args: deploy
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          PROJECT_ID: chez-mout
```

Is there something I'm doing blatantly wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`npm install` is unable to find the `package.json` file. Please make sure it exists in the root folder of your repository. (And is under version control and valid).

Answer (score 1):

I also faced with that issue, `package.json` and `package-lock.json` were existed in repo, but I didn't know about actions/checkout, in my case it helps, just add it before all of the steps:

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      with:
          sparse-checkout: .
```

You can read about actions/checkout@v4 in more details [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout)